# Is there a way to sort a string that has numerics in R?

Tags: r, string, sorting

I have a vector of strings in R that follow this format: `1:A`. So let's say I have a vector with strings

```
x = c("1:A", "201:A", "2:A")
```

I want to sort through this vector so it becomes

```
["1:A" "2:A" "201:A"]
```

Is there a function that is capable of this in R? I have tried

```
mixedsort(x, decreasing = FALSE)
```

from the `gtools` library, but it still doesn't seem to completely work very well when this vector is scaled up to include the letter `B` as well. Any ideas?

Comment: what are your example data and expected result when the "vector is scaled up to include the letter B as well".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `mixedsort`

```
library(gtools)
mixedsort(x)
#[1] "1:A"   "2:A"   "201:A"
```

---

Or remove the non-numeric characters with `gsub` and `order`

```
x[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", x)))]
#[1] "1:A"   "2:A"   "201:A"
```